# Installing python3.6 on virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x

I have python3.7 installed on my windows 10 laptop
But i need python3.6 for a specific project

Can i install it in virtualenv which will override python3.7 in that environment?

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at this thread:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713544)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this may be an appropriate solution for you. But this is what I generally follow. Just install Anaconda in your system and create an environment according to your needs. For your case create an environment for Python 3.6.

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6 
//This lines will create an environment named py36
```

You then install libraries according to your needs in that environment. You work in that environment without interfering with the libraries of the other environment. To use anaconda kindly follow [Anaconda cheatsheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf). You will get everything that you need.